# How to log out / change account of telegram after logging in with the Login Widget

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I started using the Telegram Widget API, and it works great, but I couldn't find any info on how to logout an user afterwards.
This might be useful if the user decides he wants to use a different telegram account.

Once you click the login button you get redirected to oauth.telegram.org, and if the authorization is already given you won't have the chance to logout.

The only way I found to work is the obvious approach of manually removing the cookies set to oauth.telegram.org, or to click logout on the top right corner of the authorization page, that won't show up if the authorization was already given...
[SampleBot Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAWPp.jpg)

By checking the code you can see how the logout is performed:
[Logout function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT0ic.jpg)

However, you would always need that hash for the link to work.

Then you always have the option to disconnect from telegram itself:
[Telegram disconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYN1V.jpg)

Is there any programmatic way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Comment: I just accepted that was the state of affairs at the time and haven't looked more into it

Comment: Hmm, yes, the problem is still actual. Seems, that this is potentially security hole, anybody, who will get access to the already authenticated device can just press login button and enter to the site,

Comment: As a user, you can go to Telegram Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Logged In with Telegram and disconnect yourself

Comment: Can anyone found a solution or not?